# Comparing two datasets, finding correlation and correcting/compensating

Tags: python, algorithm, math, correlation

I'm looking for some help figuring out the math required to temperature compensate my load cell data coming from my little weigh scale I'm building.

As the temperature changes the effect on the physical components and electrical components appears to have a very obvious and direct effect. The relationship seems very linear but in my limited math capabilities I've been unable to figure out how to compensate it out. I believe the

Below is a graph of this temperature related effect over ~65 hours (top plot is load cell voltage in ADC counts and bottom is temperature):

[image]

The code and the data I used to generate that image can be found here: https://repl.it/@JoshuaHenderso1/PriceyCorruptGoals#main.py

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best forum for this, but it does seem to me that it would be worth you plotting a scatter plot of voltage against temperature (rather than plotting each against time) to get an idea of what sort of relationship there is between them, and whether it would make sense to do e.g. some kind of linear regression. It would also be worth seeing if there's some kind of hardware data sheet for your detector that tells you what the temperature dependence is expected to be.